# Find domain and remove other parts from URL

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list of domain name with parameters

```
www.frontdir.com/index.php?adds1205
centurydirectory.com/submit/
www.directoryhigher.com/index.php?filec-linkapproval&x_response_code1
```

I need to find other parts with domain and I have to replace those parts.

Finally my result should look as follows.
Expected result:

```
www.frontdir.com
centurydirectory.com
www.directoryhigher.com
```

I tried the following regex

```
 /([^/\?]+)\?
```

but can not able select after " ? "

How can I attain this result?

Comment: Which language/tool are you using for this regex?

Comment: find and replace using notepad++

Comment: can you put both your expected result and actual result as part of your question?

Comment: Denim is right that would help a lot. As the question is somehow unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about replacing

```
\/.*$
```

with an empty string?

I'm assuming here that you have one URL per line (your example suggests as much) and that you want to keep just the domains (again, as per your example).